# CAST function using SQL within Excel

Tags: sql, excel, date, casting

I am facing a nightmare with one of the reports I've created.

An SQL query is run within Excel feeding various Pivot tables. If I refresh figures on my PC - all works fine, however if someone else refreshes same report on their PC, then values returned for those using CAST function are in a different format.

I'm out of ideas already, maybe anyone has any thoughts?

Thanks!

Outcome when I refresh: **2015/10/19**
Outcome when user refreshes: **2015-10-19**

Comment: Are they using the same file, do they have the same permissions etc etc, also post your code.

Comment: `CAST(l.SYS_TIMESTAMP as DATE) as WORKED_Date`   where SYS_TIMESTAMP is a datetime value.      All code is 5 pages long, but this is the bit that fails to return any values. Yes, all the user permissions are same. Values do get returned, apart from those where CAST is being used

Comment: Does `l.SYS_TIMESTAMP` on its own return anything for the user?

Comment: Check user rights for the other user and tell them to enable the active content.

Comment: Thanks, tried enabling Active Content for others and didn't help..

Comment: Your question has two different outcomes foe the user... `"if someone else refreshes same report on their PC, then no values returned "` & '"Outcome when user refreshes: 2015-10-19"'. Which one is it?

Comment: I've just noticed this Matt, thanks for pointing out! It must say "in a different format"

Comment: Right! Is there cell format different?#

Comment: No, cell format is DATE in Excel... just tried adding "execute as" at the top of the code - didn't help..

Comment: Tried changing my Windows system date settings from short date format "yyyy/mm/dd" to "yyyy-mm-dd" and saw all dates in pivots to be presented in new format, however this didn't resolve the problem when refreshed on another PC